# Interact with GUI in Objective-C while performing background task

Tags: java, c++, user-interface, cocoa

I have created a bundle that serves as a plug-in for a Cocoa application that I can only interface with via a C/C++ SDK. In accordance with the SDK, my plug-in performs a function that sets a result data object by reference and returns a result error code.

Since the developers on my team are far more experienced in Java, we built a bridge between C/C++ and Java using pipes. So when I invoke the SDK function, it sends a message to Java across the pipe instructing it to perform a Java method. The Java method sends one or more callback messages to the C/C++ SDK that will ultimately set the result data object and return the result error code for the original SDK function.

This mechanism works quite well unless my code needs to spawn a Java GUI (e.g. a color picker whose RGB values will be stored via the C/C++ SDK). I want my Java GUI to exhibit behavior similar to that of a modal child window in a pure Cocoa application. In other words, I don't want the GUI of main window to block (spinning beach ball) when I interact with it, all the while keeping the Java GUI on top of the Cocoa GUI.

What I have attempted thus far is to create a background thread that sends my method-invoking message to Java. Before that Java method spawns a GUI, I send a special message to C/C++ across the pipe. When C/C++ receives that message, I register a window observer and then start a run loop using a message port source (still on background thread) using Objective-C++.

My thought process was that since my pipe reads are blocking and I won't need to read anything else until the Java GUI is disposed, I should start a run loop in my background thread which would hopefully allow me to interact with Cocoa GUI, thereby causing a notification that my observer would recognize and bring the Java GUI back in front of the Cocoa GUI. When I dispose of the Java GUI, it would use JNI to send a remote message port request to C/C++ and stop the run loop.

Instead what happens is the main GUI blocks until I dispose of the Java GUI, and then the code I described above executes. I suppose this is because I need the main thread to wait for a result so that it can return that result to the C/C++ function. The mechanism I am using for that is a std::async that returns a std::future, upon which I call get(). I gather that my call to get() is where I am going wrong, but I am not sure how else to wait for my background thread to finish.

I am happy to provide code snippets if it helps, but I am wondering if someone can make sense of what I am describing and offer some general advice that might help me get on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the blocking problem by creating a transparent window on top of the main window of the Cocoa process and performing my operation that tells the Java process to spawn a GUI in a background thread.

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] runModalForWindow:transparentWindow]
```